# bootstrap3 with popover shows at the back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with popover. The popover box is showing up at the back of the input fields. I need it to show up on the front so it can be seen. Yes it is working for all modern browsers including IE8. However, **it breaks in IE7. I do not really like IE7. And, I have no choice as my workplace still supports IE7. I am using Bootstrap3 and popover. I do realize that BootStrap3 has dropped support for IE7. But I am so close with this except for the popover.** Then I can really sleep. Maybe have another cocacola or coffee.

Sample code below... Any idea how to solve this please

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <label class="control-label" for="custom2">Date of Birth</label>
      <img src="32005/images/iconQuestion.png" alt="Help" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="This will make up the PIN for the prepaid visa gift card" class="popUp"/> </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control input-md" value="" id="custom2" name="custom2" value="">
      <span class="mandatory"> * </span> </div>
  </div>



$(function(){
  $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you know but:

> Bootstrap 3, support for Internet Explorer 7 has been removed from the
>   project. If you need IE7 support, consider trying out bootstrap-ie7.

Disclaimer:

> Bootstrap 3 drops support for Internet Explorer 7, but you can add it
>   back by simply adding this conditional CSS.

Try it out: 
https://github.com/coliff/bootstrap-ie7

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that. It did not solve the particular issue. The popover box is just showing at the back. I tried using z-index.. didnt solve either. Thanks. I wish IE7 just died completly

Comment: Try to pull the request to boostrap-ie7; if is an issue on IE7 support they are "happy" to fix it